# Inserting data into my database isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational

I've got a nice drop down list working which is getting populated from a the table teams (FK). The only thing that isn't working is adding the data into the matches. I keep getting the following errors:

```
- team_home not set 
- team_away not set 

- Notice: Undefined index: team_home in vvo/insertmatch.php on line 28

- Notice: Undefined index: team_away in vvo/insertmatch.php on line 28

- Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your    MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'matches (team_home, team_away) VALUES ('','')' at line 1
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing these errors?

See the code below, I know it's vulnerable for sql injection, but I'd just like to get this to work.

```
**addmatch.php**

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("db.xx.nl","md190851db210288","xxx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("md190851db210288", $con);

?>
<form action="insertmatch.php" method="GET">
<select name="team_home">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT team_id, team_name FROM teams ".
"ORDER BY team_name";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['team_id']."\">".$row['team_name']."</option>\n  ";
}
?>
</select>
<select name="team_away">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT team_id, team_name FROM teams ".
"ORDER BY team_name";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['team_id']."\">".$row['team_name']."</option>\n  ";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
```

```
**insertmatch.php**

<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$con = mysql_connect("db.xx.nl","md190851db210288","xxx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

if (isset($_POST['team_home'])) { 
    echo $_POST['team_home']; 
} else { 
    echo 'team_home not set <br>'; 
}
if (isset($_POST['team_away'])) { 
    echo $_POST['team_away']; 
} else { 
    echo 'team_away not set <br>'; 
}  

mysql_select_db("md190851db210288", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO matches (team_home, team_away)
VALUES
('$_POST[team_home]','$_POST[team_away]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

echo $team_home;
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that is your code? The error says `matches(team_thuis)` and your code has `matches(team_home)` ...

Comment: You can't use FULLTEXT searches without first creating the FULLTEXT indexes.

Comment: Yeah it is, I forgot to translate those. Fixed now.

Comment: Filter all user input through `mysql_real_escape_string` or PDO before inserting it into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO matches (team_home, team_away)VALUES('%s','%s')",mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['team_home']),mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['team_away']));
```

Answer (score 1):

your PHP is not valid:

```
$_POST[team_home]
```

inside double quotes is wrong.

Put {} around it, and single quotes around team_home

{$_POST['team_home']}

and similarly for other fields. And as suggestion be aware from SQL injection, and sanitize data from $_POST before usino it in queries

Answer (score 0):

Just want to point out that what you're doing here

```
$sql="INSERT INTO matches (team_home, team_away)
VALUES
('$_POST[team_home]','$_POST[team_away]')";
```

is very dangerous.  You shouldn't using any Global variables directly.  You need to filter them and validate them or you're opening your application to SQL injection attacks.